# why ps -ef show the time like this

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ps

When I run the ps -ef command I receive something like this:

```
root     26728 26725 99 Sep25 ?        1184018564-02:43:14 java -jar /root/TaskManager.jar
```

I need to understand why the time is shown like this "1184018564-02:43:14"

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`man ps` says

```
  cputime    TIME     cumulative CPU time, "[dd-]hh:mm:ss" format. (alias time).
```

So your Java process has been running for 1184018564 CPU days (about 3,243,886 CPU years), OR ... something bad has happened.

It is [Ubuntu bug #859311](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/859311) associated with long-running multi-threaded processes.

Answer (score 0):

The UNIX time format is internally represented as a numeric value indicating the number of seconds since 1/1/1970.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_time